# Customized Alert in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

Do we have a simple alert model box in Angular 2+, I just need to use it instead of writing a component of alert customizing it and then use it.

Answer (score -2):

I used those components when I was working on Angular2 mobile. It is similar to ionic modal.
https://github.com/Jaspero/ng2-alerts